# Does anyone know the name of this Mexican Breakfast / Brunch dish?

Tags: mexican-cuisine, breakfast

I remember eating this delicious breakfast while traveling a long time ago and since it was a to go order, I never really remembered the name.

The dish had eggs (scrambled style) mixed with rice. There may have been tortilla chips but I don't remember if they were mixed or on the side.

There may have been other ingredients and I can't remember them but if someone can point them out it may jog my memory.

Comment: Did it have a tomato or refried bean sauce?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: There was sauce but not sure if it had refried beans. Also can't recall tomato but it memory serves me correctly, there was sauce (salsa)

Answer (score 4):

[*Migas*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Migas) possibly?

Scrambled egg fried with strips of tortilla, chopped vegetables, sometimes chopped meats.  Sometimes served with refried beans, that sort of thing.

It is of Spanish origin originally, rather than Mexican - probably the Tex-Mex variant, which is a bit different is what you would encounter.  Rice is included in the recipe in some regions, so entirely possible.

Comment: Gotta be migas.  I used to live in South Texas and between migas and the tachito, breakfast was always a joy.

Comment: I looked at the pictures on google images for Migas and that doesn't look like it. The quantity of rice and eggs was more visible.

Comment: @Adil: Migas has many, many forms that vary tremendously.  They can look as different from one to another as loads of bread can from each other.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing [Huevos Rancheros](http://whatscookingamerica.net/Eggs/HeuvosRanchos.htm) only because I absolutely love huevos rancheros.

It can be made with fried or scrambled eggs and maybe the place you went to added rice - it's not typical though.

The other really popular "Mexican breakfast" is [chilaquiles](http://www.familyoven.com/recipe/Chilaquiles/10721).

Rice is a pretty popular side dish so it might have just been combined instead of put on the side...

Hope hearing the names helps jog your memory (or at least eliminate) to help in your quest. It's a little hard to narrow down since eggs is really the only ingredient we can go off from.

Comment: I would also suggest making or tasting Migas b/c that looks like a very good candidate or any of the suggestions you get. Quantity of ingredients is a personal choice and so is presentation. You should see if it tastes like what you are remembering. (had to comment here coz I don't have enough rep to comment above, sorry!)